Rank of a D-module and the solution complex
For a $D$-module $M$ it is common to talk about its rank defined as the $\mathbb{C}(x_i)$-dimension of $\mathbb{C}(x_i)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[x_i]} M$. Kashiwara’s Cauchy–Kovalevskaya theorem then famously tells us that this dimension is equal to the $\mathbb{C}$-dimension of its solution space
\begin{equation}
Sol(M)= \mathrm{hom}(M,\mathbb{C}\{ x_i-y_i \})
\end{equation}
around a point $y$ outside of the singular locus. Here $\mathbb{C}\{x_i-y_i\}$ is the space of convergent power series around $y$.
However, there is also the solution complex which is often discussed. Obtained by taking the derived functor
\begin{equation}
R\mathrm{hom}(M,\mathbb{C}\{x_i-y_i\})
\end{equation}
of hom.
My question is about how the rank and this solution complex relate. Clearly, the zero-th part of this complex retrieves $\mathrm{hom}(M,\mathbb{C}\{x_i-y_i\})$. However, are there any conditions that imply that its higher parts are zero? Does the Cauchy-Kovaelvskaya theorem say anything about the other dimensions?
This heavily relates to a previous question I asked, where I asked how it can be possible that the higher parts of the solution complex are non-zero for holonomic $D$-modules given that rank is additive over exact sequences (If you have any ideas on this, please take a look at that too since I'm still not sure).
